# NPM CI error bindings not accessible from watchpack-chokidar2:fsevents

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, github-actions, package.json

When I run `npm ci` on Github Actions I got the error:

```
Run npm ci
npm ERR! bindings not accessible from watchpack-chokidar2:fsevents

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-09-17T15_18_42_465Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

What can be?

My `.github/workflows/eslint.yaml`

```
name: ESLint

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run lint
```

My `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@blinktrade/uikit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.8",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.31.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.2",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "jest": "^27.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-push": "npm run lint",
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "clear": "rimraf dist/",
    "format": "prettier '**/*' --write --ignore-unknown",
    "lint": "eslint --max-warnings=0 .",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 4000",
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved removing packages-lock.json and running again using NodeJS 14 (was 10)

Comment: In my case, it worked fine when I used the node version specified in .nvmrc file

Answer (score 3):

The `actions/setup-node@v1` must have the same version in GitHub actions and local environment where the `package-lock.json` has been built. In my case, the GitHub actions point to `node 14`.

```yaml
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "14"
```

After changing it to `16` - the same I have on the local environment - it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case my tests suddenly started failing despite having worked for a while and despite `node_version` matching my local Node version, weirdly. Simply updating this to 16 in my GitHub Action workflow fixed the issue and causes tests to start running again:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: 16
```

Answer (score 0):

For me helped update of node version

Answer (score 0):

at Build image settings I added "Node.js version 16.15" package. it helped me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).