# Error: node-notifier not accessible from @jest/reporters

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm

I am working on a React/Amplify project and I first encountered a error when building/deploying after installing the react-markdown package which I reported [here](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/663). What they told me was that the error was related to chokidar/fsevents which were occurring because I created the project on a Mac and have since moved to Windows. I followed the steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69225852/npm-ci-error-bindings-not-accessible-from-watchpack-chokidar2fsevents) post, and then encountered the following error:

```
Error: cipm can only install packages with an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json with lockfileVersion >= 1. Run an install with npm@5 or later to generate it, then try again.
```

I tried to resolve this bug by upgrading my npm version and reinstalling the packages, and now I am getting the following error:

```
Error: node-notifier not accessible from @jest/reporters
```

Comment: After upgrading, did you delete node_modules and lock file and did the install again?

Comment: @LazarNikolic thanks for the quick reply. I deleted the lock file but not the node modules. I will try that right now and let you know

Comment: @LazarNikolic It worked! Thank you so much for the help. I'm trying to understand why it worked though, since the node_modules folder is ignored by git anyway?

Comment: Deleting the folder and lock file forced npm to reinstall and rebuild everything from the start. New dependency tree was created and interconnected